# How to remove extra space in the header

Tags: php, html, css

This is the site:
http://www.indiansummerfestival.ca

Basically I want the webpage to start right at the top of the orange banner (i.e. no white space between banner and top of the page).

I tried using Chrome inspector but I have no idea where the extra 100-ish pixel amount of white space came from. The files involved is style.css and there's another chunk of css outside of the stylesheet.

I tried pasting the code but it looks pretty messy, so I think the best way is to find `<div id="header">`
 in the HTML code.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Is this happening with *every* browser?

Comment: I didn't check..but it's all good now. I end up fixing the problem with using a negative top margin for #header. The reason that I didn't use position:absolute is because I'd like the design to be responsive. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply this to compensate?

```
#header {
    margin-top:-45px;
}
```

Semi-hacks, but works? :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `#socialLinks` and `#mc_embed_signup` divs are positioned relatively as siblings to `#logo`. Despite the fact you're ofsetting those divs, they are still calculated as being in the flow, thus pushing the `#logo` down. Try positioning those 2 divs absolutely; that should fix it.

Comment: On each of them change `position:` to `absolute` and `top` to `10px`.

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem with firefox I resolved adding in my CSS :

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Ps: I am somehow unable use comments... :(

Comment: You need to gain more rep by answering questions. I would suggest not posting "Try this" answers, they tend to get downvoted heavily.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the mailchimp and social plugins that you are using. They each seem to be adding some pixels to the top. If you remove those the orange header is aligned with the top. You'll have to take a look at how those style sheets are playing with your own.